# Elixir: Sorting a list by name

Tags: elixir

Am I allowed to do this in Elixir, e.g. sort a named list?

```
list = [9,1,2,3]
Enum.sort(list)
```

To produce

```
[1,2,3,9]
```

Because I don't know what numbers are in the list I can't enter them specifically.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "named list" but your code works.

Comment: You mean to sort a list in-place? I am afraid that is not possible.

Comment: Maybe reword your question so others who read this later on will be able to figure out what you're asking. As it stands @bla had to take a guess about your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by sort a named list you meant to sort in-place, I believe that is not possible since values are immutable in elixir.

You may, however rebind the original variable so that it points to the new value:

```
iex(1)> l = [9,1,2,3]
[9, 1, 2, 3]
iex(2)> l = Enum.sort(l)
[1, 2, 3, 9]
iex(3)> l
[1, 2, 3, 9]
```

If by named list you meant [`keyword`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html), you may sort it using [`Enum.sort/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort/2) as well. To sort a keyword by value you could do something like:

```
iex(1)> k = [a: 32, b: 15] 
[a: 32, b: 15]
iex(2)> Keyword.keyword?(k)
true
iex(3)> Enum.sort(k, fn({_, v1}, {_, v2}) -> v1 <= v2 end)
[b: 15, a: 32]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for sorting a list into Ascending and Descending order. For ASC order we just need to Enum.sort() but when reverse the order we need to add comparison function while sorting.

```
a = [191, 192, 189, 190, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198]

asc = Enum.sort(a)

IO.inspect(asc, charlists: :as_lists) # [189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198]

des = Enum.sort(a, &(&1 >= &2))
IO.inspect(des, charlists: :as_lists) #[198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189]
```